# ValueError: The actor ImplicitFunc is too large (106 MiB > FUNCTION_SIZE_ERROR_THRESHOLD=95 MiB)

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, ray-tune

While I used the ray tune toolbox to find the optimal hyperparameters
I encountered the following error:

ValueError: The actor ImplicitFunc is too large (106 MiB > FUNCTION_SIZE_ERROR_THRESHOLD=95 MiB). Check that its definition is not implicitly capturing a large array or other object in scope. Tip: use ray.put() to put large objects in the Ray object store.

Could you please help me to fix this error?

Many thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.